# PieChart in Fusion Charts - Interchange the hover and display value?

Tags: pie-chart, fusioncharts

I am new to fusion charts.

How to interchange the hover value and the display value. Presently upon hover, shows the percentage value. I would need to know if the percentage and actual display value can be interchanged?

Also, if you could point to some basic documentations on fusion charts, It will help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the detail [documentation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/). You need to use the [`tooltext`](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=pie2d&attributeName=data_toolText) attribute of the `data` element to configure what text you show on hover. Look for detail [chart attributes](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=pie2d) documentation.

Hope this will solve your issue.